# Which object did send a "release" message to my property?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties, variable-assignment

There's something i don't seem to get about properties and memory management with iOS!

In my `AppDelegate`, i want a `NSString *` property :

- i've declared it this way in the `.h` file:

  @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;
- and synthetized it in the `.m`.

One of my method uses the property like this:

```
myString = [notificationDictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

(`notificationDictionary` being the `NSDictionary*` I got in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`'s `launchOptions` dictionary with the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`)

I think that means that my `AppDelegate` owns its own copy of `myString` with a retain count to 1, right?

Then another method tries to access the property, but I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception.

To be 100% sure of what was going on, I've retained my property many times and displayed the value of its retain count at each access: the retain count is decremented somewhere between the method where I give a value to my property and the method where I read it.

Which object sent the release method to my string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
myString = [notificationDictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

Does *not* make use of your synthesized property accessor. It simply sets the instance variable directly, and bypasses the automatic copying behavior.

In order to make use of your property accessors, you need to add `self.` as follows:

```
self.myString = [notificationDictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

***Update:*** I answered a similar question in more detail here: [why-does-this-property-need-the-retain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876622/why-does-this-property-need-the-retain/876639#876639)

***Update #2:*** To explain a little further, the "mystery object" that is sending a release message to your `myString` variable is actually an instance of [NSAutoreleasePool](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html), most likely the pool associated with your main thread. The value returned by `[notificationDictionary objectForKey:...]` is autoreleased, so when you assign this value to `myString`, it will only last until the end of the current run loop. When the run loop finishes, it drains the autorelease pool, sending `release` to any objects that have been flagged for autorelease. After that has happened, the pointer value in `myString` references a block of memory that has been released. This type of dead pointer is commonly called a zombie. The EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception usually occurs when you try to send a message to a zombie.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks again ! That was something I really need to know ! :)
(and although I think the Apple documentation is really well done for their API, I think their documentation about basic Objective-C concepts are hard to find and quite allusive).

Anyway, thanks again !

Comment: No worries! `:)` If you're looking for some reading material on the basic concepts, a good place to start is Apple's memory management guide: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html