# Can anyone explain what does @property(nonatomic, retain) mean with an example?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is diff. b/w @property (nonatomic,assign) and @property (nonatomic,retain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352743/what-is-diff-b-w-property-nonatomic-assign-and-property-nonatomic-retain)

I know it is used to inform the compiler to generate the getters and the setters automatically,
But I want to know what role does nonatomic, retain play here ? It would be helpful if anyone gives a clear explanation with an EXAMPLE

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375063/what-is-the-use-of-property-nonatomic-retain-statement-in-the-application

Comment: Also: [Retain attribute with property and synthesize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980488/), [Why does this property need the retain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876622/), [How is retain setter implemented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924463/)

Answer (score 1):

nonatomic means that when the property getters and setters are generated via @synthesize, they will not be implemented using any locking. So, when accessing the value it can be changed at any time and the getters and setters do not block; multiple reads/writes of the property are not serialized.

Retain will increment the retain count of the property by 1 so that it will not release when it goes out of scope. In order to free the allocated memory for the property you would then release it in dealloc